# Calling an object into memory at same time though different functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I have a MutableArray myArray with 10 Objects.

Each Object is a View with 10 differnt subViews.

Now suppose I have two NSTimers set or I am receiving some notifications from server. Each function have a code or a loop that calls objects of myArray.

Now suppose at an instant of time xxxxx an object myTField is being called by both functions and both try to setText on it. Keep in mind that the time instant is same, Will it cause memory leak issues or how will it effect the object, also if not which value will be set accordingly.

Comment: Sending messages from different threads simultaneously to the same receiver is always a potential race, and bad things may happen - unless those objects are explicitly marked _thread safe_. The receiver being an UIKit object is an excellent example: usually those objects and the "system" where the live isn't thread safe, and thus they use "main thread confinement" in order to solve many potential threading issues. That is, UIKit objects shall execute methods on the _main_ thread only (except for a few particular methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`, as others have pointed out, is generally not intended to be used from multiple threads. It is a bad type to use for this example. Let's fix that, and instead suppose that the array contains `NSMutableString`s. Let's also suppose that your intent was to say that the objects are modified by separate threads at the same time.

That said; Unless the object is declared to be thread safe for this purpose, you must assume it is a race condition and **Undefined Behavior**.

---

Noting some obvious things:

- Reference Count operations are atomic (not data races)
- Accesses to atomic properties are not data races

Comment: I think UIKit objects are an _excellent_ example for non-thread-safe objects, and they demonstrate perfectly what would happen when we try to send messages from different threads :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper yes, they're a good example of threading restrictions, but i think their own restrictions in this regard missed what i saw as the *general* question the OP was asking. i may be wrong about the OP's intent.

Answer (score 0):

As you can only (or certainly should only) update the text field on the main thread, whichever is run second will set the text. There should be no leak issues.

If your code isn't running on the main thread when it modifies the text field, change it so it is.

Comment: Well, that we need to send messages to UIKit objects only on the main thread, is the consequence of not being thread safe ;)  That is, it's not an answer to argue that you shouldn't do this anyway. No, it's actually the approach to avoid race conditions which would otherwise happen.